# How can I enable anonymous posting in OSQA?

Tags: anonymous, osqa

I am wondering about how to enable anonymous posting of question and answer in a OSQA website, like stackoverflow.com does. If OSQA does not support this feature yet, can you please give me a short brief on how can I implement a such feature like that?

Comment: move the post to Meta.StackOverflow.com

Comment: @Kangkan, why?  He's not using the StackOverflow software.

Comment: It's not matter for me. I'm expecting a positive answer than. As I see the StackOverflow is similar to OSQA too ;)

Answer (score 3):

Currently users, that are not authenticated cannot ask questions, post comments and answers. Actually the whole concept of Q&A community is based on user authorization. Just try to imagine a "community" where the one who asks is unknown (or call him a guest, if you like), and the ones who answer and comment are also unknown users.

Personally I don't think that the registration process is painful. Actually it's maximally simplified and users can get registered in less than a minute. Anyway, will be glad to hear how you think it can be improved.